# How to deploy configfile before bundles

Tags: apache-karaf, karaf

Given a feature with a <configfile> and a <bundle>, how can I ensure that the file is deployed before the bundle? What I'm seeing is that my bundle gets started first and the file deployed second (even if <configfile> is the first tag).

I guess this is could be the <bundle> being considered a pre-requisite so it makes sense to start that before processing the rest of the <feature>?

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you are doing it right, your bundles shouldn't care if the configuration is available or not. The service should either not be started or with a default setting in case no "external" configuration has been set. In case of a new configuration the service will be restarted with the new configuration.